# Unstated Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unstated

I'm using a state library called [unstated](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/unstated) and when I run the following code:

```
import { Container } from 'unstated';
import Fire from '../Core/Fire';

class Store extends Container {
  state = {
    users: [],
  };

  getAllUsers() {
    const db = Fire.firestore();
    const reference = db.collection('users');
    reference
      .get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        const docs = [];
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          docs.push(doc);
        });
        this.setState({
          users: docs.map(doc => {
            return {
              id: doc.id,
              model: doc.data(),
            };
          }),
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
}

export default Store;
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
>       at Store.js:19

I'm definitely getting results back as `docs` does contain objects at the time I want to set the state. I'm also doing things exactly the same way they are in their documentation / example.

Why isn't the reference `this` seen? Is it because it's in a promise? Doh!

Comment: Try `getAllUsers = () => { ... }` instead.

Comment: @ChrisG it works! But why? What's the difference?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 1):

You should either bind the function or use arrow function.

1.)

```
constructor(){
this.getAllUsers=this.getAllUsers.bind(this) 
}
```

2)

```
getAllUsers = () =>{ ... }
```